# cannot load such file -- 'nokogiri\nokogiri' ruby 2.7

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm running AWS Lambda locally.

When I run the lambda function this is the error I get:

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.0.rc2/lib/nokogiri.rb:15:in `rescue in <top (required)>'",
    "/var/task/vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.0.rc2/lib/nokogiri.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.5/lib/google_drive/session.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.5/lib/google_drive.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/main.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

I looked into `/var/task/vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.0.rc2/lib/nokogiri.rb:15`and this is the code that makes everything blow up: `require 'nokogiri/nokogiri'

These are the files in `./vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.0.rc2/lib':

```
nokogiri
nokogiri.rb
xsd
```

And these are the files in `./vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.11.0.rc2/lib/nokogiri/`:

```
css
decorators
html.rb
nokogiri.bundle
version.rb
xml.rb
xslt.rb
css.rb
html
jruby
syntax_error.rb
xml
xslt
```

There is no file `nokogiri/nokogiri` hence I suppose the error. I tried to copy `nokogiri.rb` into directory `nokogiri` nut other errors pop up.

How can I move forward?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you ever solve this?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, never got it solved since I moved on to a different project. Hopefully, someone runs into the same issue and posts a solution. Sorry, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same exact problem until I read this article https://www.stevenringo.com/ruby-in-aws-lambda-with-postgresql-nokogiri/ .

To summarize, the problem is when using an AWS Lambda, there is no way to execute a command on the environment/Lambda. So while you can use `bundle install` locally, you CANNOT use it when on the Lambda. That being said and as the article mentions,  `we need to find a way to package and compile dependencies ahead of time in an environment that is compatible with the Lambda environment.`

This leads us to an alternate solution of compiling our dependencies from the docker container to match the lambda environment. In order to fix the problem, you need to do the following:

1. Install docker on your local machine
2. Create a `Dockerfile` in your ruby project with the following lines:

   ```
   FROM lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.7

   CMD "/bin/bash"
   ```
3. Build your docker image with the following command: `docker build -t lambda-ruby2.7 .` (Don't forget the period at the end!)
4. Enter the shell inside the container with the following command:
   `docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/var/task -w /var/task lambda-ruby2.7`
5. From the shell/container, run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle --clean`
6. Exit the shell
7. Inside the project, zip it: `zip -q -r deploy.zip .`

This solution worked for me. Hopefully it can be an alternative until someone figures how to do this without using Docker.